# How can I find any control in the ItemTemplate of a TabControl?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl

```
 <TabControl 
    Name="myTabControl"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">                            
               <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                           <DockPanel Width="120">
                                <Button Name="CloseScreen"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                          </DockPanel>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
 </TabControl>
```

I want to find the button which is located in the ItemTemplate from code.

Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask what you are intending to do with the button once you have found it? With WPF there's often an alternative way of accomplishing a task which doesn't involve manipulating controls directly.

Comment: I want to bind controls to ViewModel objects conventionally at runtime using control name and ViewModel property/method name. In this way I should set the Command property of the button dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.findlogicalnode(v=VS.100).aspx). For example:

```
var button = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(myTabControl, "CloseScreen");
```

But beware: because you're using a DataTemplate for your tab items, you'll end up with multiple buttons called CloseScreen, and FindLogicalNode will probably only return the first.

Another approach is to search the logical tree recursively using [`LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598654(v=VS.100).aspx). The problem you might face here is knowing when to stop.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is using the click event, try using a command instead.

Comment: No, I want to find the button instance at runtime.